# Asp.net MVC Web Application to PhoneGap

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc, cordova

Ive got a asp.net mvc web application. I'm wanting to use phoneGap to convert it to a ios application. Im reading through the getting started doco's on the PhoneGap website which is saying that the website needs to be served in Apache Cordova, which I cant see is able to serve an asp.net website.

Any ideas on how you use phoneGap on an asp.net mvc site?

Thanks

Comment: am not sure if what you're asking for can be done or not, but as a general comment, if I were you, I would consider Monotouch since it is for C# and .net so if any library can do what you want, my guess is that it should be Monotouch rather than Phonegap http://xamarin.com/monotouch

Comment: do you need server side? or you can build static files (html) and use `jsonp` to bring the data to your application